# How to escape single quote within sql statement which is inside a variable value?

Tags: java, sql, logging, log4j, escaping

For log4j I have this very simple sql statement:

```
log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO [LOG].[dbo].[LOGS] VALUES('%m')
```

`%m` is a variable which contains the message of the logger. Sometimes this message will also contain `'` in it. For example: `User 'Admin' deleted object C333421`  (rough example)

How can I escape it?

Answer (score 1):

You escape single quotes by using two single quotes. So for example

`User ''Admin'' deleted object C333421`

You need to change the String in your java code that retrieves the message.

You can use `replaceAll` for this

`message = message.replaceAll("'", "''"));`

Or you could use `REPLACE('%m', '''', '''''')` in the `sql`statement

Comment: it's log4j - i can't change modules which retrieve the log message. so the variable %m - will come as it is. I mean the string which it'll have may have `'` in it. so i can't do changes to the java code and am limited to doing tricks with sql statement :(

Comment: You could try using `REPLACE('%m', '''', '')`

Comment: Just tried. This doesn't work. here is an example of the line which %m carries:

`Operations are performed by user 'Administrator'. User URL: 'app://reflection/c3333'`

i see all other lines loged into DB except these lines. these lines I see in the parallel file based log. and also jboss server log complains about failed sql statement on these lines:(

Comment: Just updated the answer, please try that. If it doesn't work then I will have run out of ideas :)